# Principal component analysis representing pre-computed clusters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

Is there a way to do principal components analysis on a set of variables from a CSV file, while plotting with different colors precomputed clusters and label their centroids, if such properties are specific columns of the CSV file.

Let's say I have hundred of columns in which I want to perform the PCA and I want to compute PCs for every entry of the CSV file, but I want to plot with a different color based on the cluster_id column (0,1,2,etc.) and label their centroids with a marker different than the standard one.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you have multiple csv files?

Comment: @DataJanitor No, there was a typo. There's a single csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use seaborn or matplotlib for that. Give a dataframe with `cluster_id`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=PCA_RESULTS[:, 0], y=PCA_RESULTS[:, 1] hue=data['cluster_id'], style=data['cluster_id'])
```

where PCA_RESULTS is the first two principal components of the pca run, and data['cluster_id'] is the information used to color the dots in the scatterplot. The `style` parameter is used to set markers for each cluster id.